# Making a bot execute a set of actions simultaneously in Python (Using selenium)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, multitasking

I made a bot with Selenium that opens a browser and fills with the data of a different person a form for each person I have on a list (or dictionary, not important here) (it opens a browser with a different proxy each time).

**I'd like to make it to open, let's say if I have 10 people in that list, then open 10 browser windows and complete them at the same time, each one with the data of a different person from that list.**

My bot works fine, it just executes one cicle at a time (opens a browser and completes one form, then opens another browser and completes it, then another and so on)

**How should I approach this? What should I take in consideration? (I guess it might take more ressources) Should I do that? Is there any efficient way to achive that?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using some basic multi-threading.
I recommend this guide by Jim Anderson:

[An Intro to Threading in Python](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/)

Edit: Remember to not interact with one variable using two different threads.